# Specifying astype() for reading columns of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

There is a dataframe with two columns where the first is an integer number and the second is a float number:

```
       inst    weight
0    126400  0.845194
1   4382592  0.083728
```

If I use `row = df.iloc[0].astype(float)` then the first column is also converted to float. I would like to statically specify int and float and assign them to variables, e.g.:

```
w = df['weight'].iloc[0].astype(float)
i = df['inst'].iloc[0].astype(int)
```

But that results in an error like `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'astype'`. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the whole column as the type.

Like:

```
df['weight'] = df['weight'].astype(float)
```